# engine.h is not recognized in Visual Studio c++

Tags: c++, matlab

I've make all the settings in Visual for this code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define BUFSIZE 1000



int main ()
{
Engine *ep;
if (!(ep = engOpen("\0"))) {
    fprintf(stderr, "\nCan't start MATLAB engine\n");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

and i still get this error:

Error   2   error C2065: 'Engine' : undeclared identifier
Error   3   error C2065: 'ep' : undeclared identifier
Error   4   error C2065: 'ep' : undeclared identifier
Error   5   error C3861: 'engOpen': identifier not found

Comment: Those identifiers have to be declared *somewhere*.  None of the header files in your code snippet declare them.  Your question title says "engine.h" is not recognized in Visual Studio.  According to your code, you are not even including it, so of course any declarations in that file would not be recognized.  What happens when you add a `#include` directive for it?

Comment: I added #include "engine.h". I receive no error when compiling, but when the application starts I receive a system error: 'The program can't start because libeng.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix the problem.'

Comment: Ensure that libeng.dll and all other dependencies are in the same directory as the main executable, or at least in your PATH environment variable.